# Angular4 routing is not working in IE while its working fine in Mozilla and chrome

Tags: java, angular, tomcat, frontend

Hi I have created a angular4 app with tomcat server and all my routes are working fine in chrome and Mozilla while the same routes are not working on IE11.

Things i have tried

1.changes in polyfills.ts for IE browser

2. useHash: true

but these changes not worked for me.

basically i want to handle the reload button functionality with the routes which is working fine for mozilla and chrome but not working in IE11.

Comment: Try checking the content-type, it might be that IE is not happy with the content type you are returning from server. If i remember correctly it does not support json, not sure now.

Comment: Any error log maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding an extra path,appended with my war name. I had one path 'index.html', mapped to first route, but for IE it required path : 'myApp/index.html', where myApp is my tomcat war name.

for chrome :

> path: 'index.html', redirectTo: '/abc/admin'

for IE :

> path: 'myapp/index.html', redirectTo: '/abc/admin'